# Disable a button after submitting form when form already has form.valid field set for [disabled] field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a reactive form, which consists of a button and two other fields.

I have set a validator. If validator is true, I am enabling the button via 'FormName.valid' and similarly if it's false, the button is disabled

**What I want?**

I want to disable button, after clicking on Submit button as well

**What I tried?**

I tried `FormName.reset()`, which does disable the button, but then it shows errors in the background for empty two fields, while my spinner is running. (So, I don't want to do like this)

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="FormName" (ngSubmit)=sendData()>
       // Two other fields here
        <div id="frame-send-button" text-center>
            <button [disabled]="!FormName.valid" type="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
</form>
```

**Typescript**

Form Initialization

```
this.FormName= new FormGroup({
        field1: new FormControl(this.field1value, Validators.required),
        field2: new FormControl(this.field2value)
    }, IsFutureValidator('somevalidator'));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not a click event listener containing document.getElementById('submitForm').disabled = 'disabled';
    },

Comment: Also you have an extra "}" in your script.

Comment: @shadoe2020 I don't get '.disabled', as an option in document.getElementbyId

Comment: how about .setAttribute('disabled')

Comment: It works! Thanks. You can submit it as an answer, if you want me to accept it.

Comment: my pleasure, I've added it and good luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.yourQuerySelector('submitForm').setAttribute('disabled');
```

This will add an attribute of your choice to any element. "Disabled" will work in this case.